# Assign email on user registeration

Tags: users, emails

I have a custom user `email` field, 
I want when the user signs up to automatically set the email for he/she.

For example, when the username field is `user1` I want set the email to `user1@mydomain.com` and save it in email field.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to customize the user registration form, you're probably looking at a custom module to take care of this; an invocation of [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) can step in and alter the behavior of the user registration form. For example, adding the following functions to MYMODULE:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // Disable the email field
  $form['account']['mail']['#access'] = FALSE;

  // @TODO: Override validation functions in $form['#validate'] 
  // that check the mail field

  // Replace the user registration form submission with
  // the function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_submit 
  $form['#submit'] = array('MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_submit');
}

// Alter the disabled mail field before 
// submitting registration form to user_register_submit()
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_submit($form_id, &$form_state) {
  // add '@mydomain.com' to the submitted username field
  $form_state['values']['mail'] = $form_state['values']['name'] .  '@mydomain.com';
  user_register_submit($form_id, $form_state);
}
```

This only get you partially there, as overriding such key functionality requires many scenarios to validate now that a key assumption is gone (e.g. what happens when someone enters an email for a name, what happens when a user needs to recover password, etc.).

It might be helpful to look at the source code of the [Optional mail on register](https://www.drupal.org/project/optional_mail) module to see how that is accomplished so you can under how modules can override Drupal's user registration functionality.